# Get data dynamically and show it on a bottom-docked DIV - jQuery Ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have a project of creating an interface to list about 50 Radio Stations.
Now, I have the interface listing all the 50 radios, and station switching without page reload. I currently use a DIV docked on the bottom of the page with Divs hidden, then when the user click on a station logo, it change the div content and show the requested station's content along with player.
But as the page loads with all station's Divs hidden along with their content, it take very long to load.
So, I would like to simply the playback still preventing page reload onclick but this time by using a dinamical script like PHP, jQuery, Ajax. Here is an example of what I would like to realize with the help of the good guys here: http://www.radioways.fr/webradios/radio-fm.html

Instead of loading all the stations ones, I would like to list them in MySQL and use a PHP/jQuery/Ajax script to get the requested station data from the DB and replace it with the current data in the docked DIV at the bottom (station name, playing url, contact etc... )

I'm seeking help from gentle guys here who may have already a similar script or advice me any way to follow....

Thanks in advance,

Thank you TymeJV for getting back to me. But I'm very limited in PHP coding, that's why I was asking for a full sample code is possible.

Here is the HTML/JavaScript code I'm using currently:
JS in the Header:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var speed = 500; 
    var animating = false;

    $("a.nav").click(function(){
        if ((!animating) && $("#"+$(this).attr("rel")).is(":hidden"))
        {
            animating = true;
            var requestedDiv = "#"+$(this).attr("rel");
            $("#radiolisting").children("div").each(function(){$(this).fadeOut(speed/2)});
            $("#radiolisting").animate({height: $(requestedDiv).height()}, speed);
            $(requestedDiv).delay(speed/1.5).fadeIn(speed);
            setTimeout(function(){animating = false}, speed*2);
        }
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

The HTML for listing the Radio Station:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <title>000000</title>



    <style type="text/css">
    #radiolisting div{display:none}
    #radiolisting div#001{display:block}
    </style>


     <link href="css/melo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />



     </head>

    <body>
    <!--start container -->
    <div id="container">



    <div class="content" align="center">
         <div height="160" width="430"><img class="float-center" src="images/logo.png" align="center"  /></a>
         <br />
    </div>    



         <main>    



            <!--station logo listing with rel to change the content without reloading the page -->


          <div class="box" id="box">
          <a href="#" class="nav" title="Radio" rel="001"><img class="float-left" src="radio/002.jpg" alt="Click here to listen to this Station" align="center" height="83" width="160" /></a>
            </div>

          <div class="box" id="box">
          <a  href="#" class="nav" title="Radio" rel="003"><img class="float-left" src="radio/003.gif" alt="Click here to listen to this Station" align="center" height="83" width="160" /></a>   
          </div>

          <div class="box" id="box">
          <a href="#" class="nav" title="Radio" rel="004"><img class="float-left" src="radio/004.jpg" alt="Click here to listen to this Station" height="83" width="160" /></a>  
          </div>

          <div class="box" id="box">
          <a href="#" class="nav" title="Radio" rel="005"><img class="float-left" src="radio/005.png" alt="Click here to listen to this Station" height="83" width="160" /></a>  
          </div>

          <div class="box" id="box">
          <a href="#" class="nav" title="Radio Cenner FM Dakar" rel="ceeneer"><img class="float-left" src="radio/006.jpg" alt="Click here to listen to this Station" height="83" width="160" /></a>  
          </div>

          <div class="box" id="box">
          <a href="#" class="nav" title="Radio Jant bi FM Touba" rel="jantbifm"><img class="float-left" src="radio/007.jpg" alt="Click here to listen to this Station" height="83" width="160" /></a>  
          </div>

           <div class="box" id="box">
          <a href="#" class="nav" title="Radio 000" rel="008"><img class="float-left" src="radio/008jpg" alt="00" height="83" width="160" /></a>  
          </div>

          <div class="box" id="box">
          <a href="#" class="nav" title="Radio 000" rel="lampfm"><img class="float-left" src="radio/009" alt="Click here to listen to this Station" height="83" width="160" /></a>  
          </div>







    </div>
        </main>


    </div>
    <!--end container -->
    <!--station content listing -->
    <div id="radiolisting">

        <div id="002" class="rajo">
        <p class="leeral"> 
        Nom De la Station: 000<br />
        Frequence FM  MHz: n/a <br />
        Site de Transmission: Italie <br />
        Contact : Skype en Direct: <a href="skype:000?call"><img src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_transparent_34x34.png" style="border: none;" width="34" height="34" alt="000" /></a>

        </p>

    <p style="float:left; padding-left: 5px;">
    radio player embed code</div>

        <div id="002" class="rajo">
        <p class="leeral"> 
        Nom De la Station: 000<br />
        Frequence FM  MHz: n/a <br />
        Site de Transmission: Italie <br />
        Contact : Skype en Direct: <a href="skype:000?call"><img src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_transparent_34x34.png" style="border: none;" width="34" height="34" alt="000" /></a>

        </p>

    <p style="float:left; padding-left: 5px;">
    radio player embed code</div>

        <div id="003" class="rajo">
        <p class="leeral"> 
        Nom De la Station: 000<br />
        Frequence FM  MHz: n/a <br />
        Site de Transmission: Italie <br />
        Contact : Skype en Direct: <a href="skype:000?call"><img src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_transparent_34x34.png" style="border: none;" width="34" height="34" alt="000" /></a>

        </p>

    <p style="float:left; padding-left: 5px;">
    radio player embed code</div>

        <div id="004" class="rajo">
        <p class="leeral"> 
        Nom De la Station: 000<br />
        Frequence FM  MHz: n/a <br />
        Site de Transmission: Italie <br />
        Contact : Skype en Direct: <a href="skype:000?call"><img src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_transparent_34x34.png" style="border: none;" width="34" height="34" alt="000" /></a>

        </p>

    <p style="float:left; padding-left: 5px;">
    radio player embed code</div>

        <div id="005" class="rajo">
        <p class="leeral"> 
        Nom De la Station: 000<br />
        Frequence FM  MHz: n/a <br />
        Site de Transmission: Italie <br />
        Contact : Skype en Direct: <a href="skype:000?call"><img src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_transparent_34x34.png" style="border: none;" width="34" height="34" alt="000" /></a>

        </p>

    <p style="float:left; padding-left: 5px;">
    radio player embed code</div>

        <div id="006" class="rajo">
        <p class="leeral"> 
        Nom De la Station: 000<br />
        Frequence FM  MHz: n/a <br />
        Site de Transmission: Italie <br />
        Contact : Skype en Direct: <a href="skype:000?call"><img src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_transparent_34x34.png" style="border: none;" width="34" height="34" alt="000" /></a>

        </p>

    <p style="float:left; padding-left: 5px;">
    radio player embed code</div>

    <div id="007" class="rajo">
        <p class="leeral"> 
        Nom De la Station: 000<br />
        Frequence FM  MHz: n/a <br />
        Site de Transmission: Italie <br />
        Contact : Skype en Direct: <a href="skype:000?call"><img src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_transparent_34x34.png" style="border: none;" width="34" height="34" alt="000" /></a>

        </p>

    <p style="float:left; padding-left: 5px;">
    radio player embed code</div>

        <div id="008" class="rajo">
        <p class="leeral"> 
        Nom De la Station: 000<br />
        Frequence FM  MHz: n/a <br />
        Site de Transmission: Italie <br />
        Contact : Skype en Direct: <a href="skype:000?call"><img src="http://download.skype.com/share/skypebuttons/buttons/call_blue_transparent_34x34.png" style="border: none;" width="34" height="34" alt="000" /></a>

        </p>

    <p style="float:left; padding-left: 5px;">
    radio player embed code</div>
    </div>  

      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple actually, since there's no code above, I'll give ya some sample code. So, your div at the bottom dock probably looks something along the lines of:

```
<div id="ajaxContainer"></div>
```

And your radios should contain the `value` of the station to send back to the server to query on:

```
<input type="radio" name="station" value="rock101.7" /> Rock Radio!
```

Now, you're going to want a `change` event that triggers when a radio is clicked:

```
$(":radio[name=station]").change(function() {
    //Lets start that AJAX
    $.ajax({
        url: url, //url to php func
        data: {radio: this.value}, //this.value will be whatever the value attr of the radio element is, in this case: "rock101.7"
        dataType: 'json', //change to whatever datatype your RECEIVING from the server
        success: function(data) {
            //data is the data received back from the server, so just send it to your container
            $("#ajaxContainer").html(data); //replace all content in  #ajaxContainer with your content back from the server
        }
    });
});
```

On the PHP side of things, you can receive your POST variable with a simple:

```
$param = $_POST['radio']; //radio is the key we defined above in the 'data' portion of the AJAX call.
```

And that's basically it!

Comment: @Ilimaan -- Im not really sure how much more full sample you want than this, I have zero idea what your backend looks like. You'll need to take some PHP crash course tutorials and guides to get it up and running.

Comment: Thank you TymeJV, I added the HTML/JS code I'm currently using. Please review it and see what you can suggest me to improve it.